# Zend 2 in combination with Netbeans and WAMP

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans, web-deployment

I have succesfully installed and deployed the Zend skeleton application however when netbeans open the page it doesn't show the actual page of Zend but it shows the Index of /testzendwithwamp and i have no clue what the problem is.

I am using WAMP and i copy the full project map into the www folder of C:/wamp/www as i was told and as it works with other php sites. For some reason however this won't work with Zend 2 now i assume that it has something to do with the fact that Netbeans/WAMP has no clue which .php file to load but i have no clue how to fix it does anyone have experience with this that could help me please? i'm kind of stuck

Comment: You need to run the index.php in the public folder. So probably in your case: `/testzendwithwamp/public`

Comment: if i run either /testzendwithwamp/public or /testzendwithwamp/public/index.php it gives me a 500 error

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: appereantly i forgot to enable rewrite modules in my WAMP server